# Quadratic programming in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, graph-theory, mathematical-optimization

I'm looking at quadratic relaxation of maximum independent set problem (p.22 [here](http://etd.fcla.edu/UF/UFE0001011/butenko_s.pdf)), and found that `FindMaximum` fails for every graph I try, unless I give it optimal solution as the starting point. These quadratic programmes have 10-20 variables, so I expect them to be solvable.

1. Is there a way to make Mathematica solve such quadratic programmes?
2. Is there some quadratic programming package that's easy to call from within Mathematica?

Here's an example of failing `FindMaximum`, followed by working `FindMaximum` initialized at the solution

```
setupQuadratic[g_Graph] := (
   Ag = AdjacencyMatrix[g];
   A = IdentityMatrix[Length@VertexList@g] - Ag;
   cons = And @@ Table[0 <= x[v] <= 1, {v, VertexList@g}];
   vars = x /@ VertexList[g];
   indSet = FindIndependentVertexSet@g;
   xOpt = Array[Boole[MemberQ[indSet, #]] &, {Length@VertexList@g}];
   );

g = GraphData[{"Cubic", {10, 11}}];
setupQuadratic[g];
FindMaximum[{vars.A.vars, cons}, vars]
FindMaximum[{vars.A.vars, cons}, Thread[{vars, xOpt}]]
```

Here are other graphs I tried

```
{"DodecahedralGraph", "FruchtGraph", "TruncatedPrismGraph", \
"TruncatedTetrahedralGraph", {"Cubic", {10, 2}}, {"Cubic", {10, 
   3}}, {"Cubic", {10, 4}}, {"Cubic", {10, 6}}, {"Cubic", {10, 
   7}}, {"Cubic", {10, 11}}, {"Cubic", {10, 12}}, {"Cubic", {12, 
   5}}, {"Cubic", {12, 6}}, {"Cubic", {12, 7}}, {"Cubic", {12, 
   9}}, {"Cubic", {12, 10}}}
```

Comment: The paper you linked is very nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Might try method shown in package located [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6530/). See problem 8

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: interesting, thanks. BTW, I'm also getting good results by using SDP relaxation of the quadratic program -- http://mathematica-bits.blogspot.com/2011/03/semidefinite-programming-in-mathematica.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `Maximize` will serve you better. Here is a modified version of your function, which returns a list of 2 results - the "manual" one and the one obtained by `Maximize`:

```
Clear[findIVSet];
findIVSet[g_Graph] :=
Module[{Ag, A, cons, vars, indSet, indSetFromMaximize, xOpt},
  Ag = AdjacencyMatrix[g];
  A = IdentityMatrix[Length@VertexList@g] - Ag;
  cons = And @@ Table[0 <= x[v] <= 1, {v, VertexList@g}];
  vars = x /@ VertexList[g];
  indSet = FindIndependentVertexSet@g;
  xOpt = Array[Boole[MemberQ[indSet, #]] &, {Length@VertexList@g}];
  {indSet, DeleteCases[vars /. (Last@
    Maximize[{vars.A.vars, cons}, vars,Integers] /. (x[i_] -> 1) :> (x[i] -> i)), 0]}];
```

Here are the results:

```
In[32]:= graphs = GraphData /@ {"DodecahedralGraph", "FruchtGraph", 
"TruncatedPrismGraph", "TruncatedTetrahedralGraph", {"Cubic", {10, 2}}, {"Cubic", {10, 
  3}}, {"Cubic", {10, 4}}, {"Cubic", {10, 6}}, {"Cubic", {10, 
  7}}, {"Cubic", {10, 11}}, {"Cubic", {10, 12}}, {"Cubic", {12, 
  5}}, {"Cubic", {12, 6}}, {"Cubic", {12, 7}}, {"Cubic", {12, 
  9}}, {"Cubic", {12, 10}}};


In[33]:= sets = findIVSet /@ graphs

Out[33]= {{{1, 2, 3, 8, 10, 11, 17, 20}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 14, 15, 17, 18}},
{{2, 4, 6, 11, 12}, {2, 4, 6, 11, 12}}, {{2, 7, 10, 12, 16, 18}, {8, 11, 13, 16, 17, 18}}, 
{{1, 4, 7, 12}, {4, 7, 9, 12}}, {{2,3, 8, 9}, {2, 3, 8, 9}}, {{1, 4, 7, 10}, {2, 5, 8, 9}}, 
{{1, 4, 7, 10}, {2, 4, 7, 9}}, {{2, 4, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 7, 9}}, {{2, 5, 8, 9}, {2, 5, 8, 9}}, 
{{1, 3, 7, 10}, {4, 5, 8, 9}}, {{1, 6, 8, 9}, {2, 3, 6, 10}}, {{1, 6, 7, 12}, {4, 5, 9, 10}}, 
{{3, 4, 7, 8, 12}, {3, 4, 7, 8, 12}}, {{1, 5, 8, 9}, {4, 5, 10, 11}}, 
{{1, 5, 6, 9, 10}, {3, 4, 7, 8, 12}}, {{3, 4, 7, 9, 10}, {3, 4, 7, 9, 10}}}
```

They are not always the same for "manual" ones and those from `Maximize`, but then there is more than 
one solution for an independent set. The results from `Maximize` are all independent sets, which is easily verified:

```
In[34]:= MapThread[IndependentVertexSetQ, {graphs, sets[[All, 2]]}]

Out[34]= {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
True, True,True}
```

Comment: Well, I already have the independent set from FindIndependentVertexSet, which might internally use something like what you propose, I'm actually interested in finding maximum of the original quadratic, Real domain

Comment: @Yaroslav  Why are you interested in the real domain? As far as I could see, it is clearly stated in the paper you linked, that all variables can only have values 0 or 1 (that is, Integer domain). And, for that matter, what makes you think that the results for the real domain will have anything to do with the maximal independent set problem? It seems quite clear that we are not searching for local extrema here, so the constraints are important. Extrema found with continuous constraints can be quite different from those with discrete constraints. Or did I totally miss the point?

Comment: Because solving it in Integer domain is NP-complete, whereas real-valued QP programming is tractable. Discarding integer constraints is known as a "relaxation", and it works surprisingly well for certain classes of graphs   -- http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5170/lp-relaxation-of-independent-set

Comment: @Yaroslav It is tractable but maximizing is nonconvex (minimizing in this case is convex). So no guarantees of globality.

Comment: Interesting, I guess this QP is not as easy as I thought. Apparently such non-convex QP problems are known as "Box-QP"

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the reason FindMaximum doesn't work here is the wild nature of your function. I tried a grid with 1,048,576 samples in variable space and none achieve a higher value than zero. Your optimum starting value gets -20.

```
In[10]:= (x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + x[3]^2 - 2 x[3] x[4] + x[4]^2 - 
  2 x[2] (x[3] + x[4]) + x[5]^2 - 2 x[3] x[6] - 2 x[5] x[6] + 
  x[6]^2 - 2 x[5] x[7] + x[7]^2 - 2 x[6] x[8] - 2 x[7] x[8] + 
  x[8]^2 - 2 x[7] x[9] + x[9]^2 - 2 x[1] (x[2] + x[5] + x[9]) - 
  2 x[4] x[10] - 2 x[8] x[10] - 2 x[9] x[10] + x[10]^2 /. 
 Thread[vars -> #]) & @@@ Tuples[{0.0, 0.333, 0.667, 1.0}, 10] // Max
```

`Out[10]= 0`.

```
In[11]:= (x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + x[3]^2 - 2 x[3] x[4] + x[4]^2 - 
 2 x[2] (x[3] + x[4]) + x[5]^2 - 2 x[3] x[6] - 2 x[5] x[6] + 
 x[6]^2 - 2 x[5] x[7] + x[7]^2 - 2 x[6] x[8] - 2 x[7] x[8] + 
 x[8]^2 - 2 x[7] x[9] + x[9]^2 - 2 x[1] (x[2] + x[5] + x[9]) - 
 2 x[4] x[10] - 2 x[8] x[10] - 2 x[9] x[10] + x[10]^2 /. 
Thread[vars -> #]) & @@@ {xOpt}

Out[11]= {-20}
```

Comment: The objective above simplifies to `Times[-20,Power[Slot[1],2]]` after `ReplaceAll`. One way to evaluate original objective is `vars.A.vars /. Thread[vars -> xOpt]`

Comment: btw, above can be fixed if you replace `@@@` with `/@` or `#` with `{##}` (but not both at the same time!)

Comment: I expanded vars.A.vars because it saves a factor of 2.3 in time on my machine. I am aware the 2nd part could have been written differently. I just did it this way to keep the structure of the code the same.

Comment: my point is that there's a bug, objective should be `4` at `xOpt`, not `-20`